# Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure

Tags: android-studio-3.0, google-maps-api-2

Android Studio 3.6

I added the following in my app/build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

In **google_maps_api.xml**, I've added my API key like this:

```
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIzaSyAu_1111111</string>
```

In manifest file:

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyAu_1111111" />
```

On google console my API key is ENABLED

Here's my layout:

```
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileDetailsToolbar"
tools:context=".ui.activity.MapActivity" />
```

Here's my actvity:

```
class MapActivity : RootActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        dataBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.map_activity)
        dataBinding.setHandler(this)


        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolBar))
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        getSupportActionBar()?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

But when I start my activity the map is not show.
In logcat I get the next error:

```
12-20 09:59:10.675 E/Google Maps Android API( 5153): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-20 09:59:10.676 E/Google Maps Android API( 5153): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
12-20 09:59:10.676 E/Google Maps Android API( 5153): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
12-20 09:59:10.676 E/Google Maps Android API( 5153): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
12-20 09:59:10.676 E/Google Maps Android API( 5153):    API Key: YOUR_API_KEY
12-20 09:59:10.676 E/Google Maps Android API( 5153):    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): some_hex_value;com.myproject
```

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites.

Comment: Make sure you're building an apk from same pc when you generate SHA else you need to add another one and also check API key with current project you have added in console

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using an API key, the error could be caused by any of the following:

- using an API key but from a project without a valid billing account
- using an invalid/incorrect/malformed API key
- using an API key which is restricted to other applications aside from your own
- Maps SDK for Android is not enabled on your project

Make sure you are using an API key from a project that has a valid billing account since it is  stated in [Maps SDK for Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) that before you can start using the Google Maps Platform APIs and SDKs, you must sign up and create a billing account.

Also, if your API key has restrictions, make sure that it is properly restricted according to the [API key best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey). And lastly, make sure that you have enabled Maps SDK for Android for your maps project in the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).